# How do I handle the return object of a service call in ASPX MVC V3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry bout the vague question, I'm not sure how to succinctly phrase my problem.

I have a ASPX MVC V3 project.

The walkthrough of a form submission goes

1. `CreateCustomer` view holds the form and is viewed by the customer
2. Customer submits form
3. Form POST to `CreateCustomer` and in turn calls the `CreateCustomer` method with the `[HttpPost]` tag.
4. The `[HttpPost] CreateCustomer()` method calls an `external CreateCustomer service`.
5. The `external CreateCustomer service` returns an `SuccessObject`
6. **?????????**
7. I show the `CreateCustomerResult` page which uses the `SuccessObject`.

I don't know/understand how to do step 6.

I'm in the controller, in the CreateCustomer method, I have the object I want to show, **how do I move from `CreateCustomer` to `CreateCustomerResult`?**

I tried to use `RedirectToAction` but it didn't allow me to pass the object along with it. I also think this is the wrong method to use?

Any thoughts?

Once again sorry if this seems a bit vague, I think I'm confused here.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this. Return your results view in `HttpPost` method

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreateCustomer()
    {
       return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateCustomer()
    {
     try{
        // save here
         return view("CreateCustomerResult",SuccessObject)
        }catch(Exception ex) 
        {
        ///
           return view("CreateCustomerResult",SuccessObject)
        }

    }
```

Comment: That sounds too easy! *runs away to test now*

Comment: Great & Good luck with that !